Does Flutter have RUNTIME environment variables?
From what I can tell, Flutter doesn't have the ability to set true runtime environment variables.  What Flutter calls environment variables seem to be nothing more than build arguments. I would be happy to be proven wrong on this.
For example, you can pass in environment variables (build args) like so: flutter build web --dart-define MY_ENV_VAR=foobar.  I don't see how I can pass in a change to an environment variable after flutter build web, however.
This makes dockerizing a Flutter web app with runtime environment variables impossible. If flutter build web --dart-define MY_ENV_VAR=foobar is in my dockerfile, then the environment variables are baked into the image.
Here is how I am trying to read an env var:
const myEnvVar = String.fromEnvironment('MY_ENV_VAR', defaultValue: 'foobar');

So is there a way to do docker run -p 80:80 -e MY_ENV_VAR=foobar my-flutter-web-app?
This related question elaborates on my problem.

Rephrased: how do I fetch/use runtime app config instead of environment variables in flutter

@AdamJenkins If that would help me achieve my goal, then sure.

you just want config, right? Fetch it from a server (or read it from one of multiple config files that are bundled in your app) and stick it in a class and have your app use it.

@AdamJenkins If I understand you correctly, yes I just want config, but I want different configs for the same docker image. So at runtime I can have docker run -p 80:80 -e MY_ENV_VAR=prodValue my-flutter-web-app for a prod deployment, and docker run -p 80:80 -e MY_ENV_VAR=devValue my-flutter-web-app for a dev deployment.

Put both sets of configs in config files - like config.dev.yaml and config.prod.yaml - and rename the config you want to use (as specified by your env variable) to config.yaml before you start your app, and have your flutter app always look for config in config.yaml. Runtime config

@AdamJenkins Could you elaborate on this approach? We can take it to a private chat if needed.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In case you want env without rebuilding, you know flutter app is still a webapp. You can have js channel to load different .env files and read the config from there.  This is not the most flutter friendly answer but it would get the job done.

@Rahul.  ChatGPT actually gave me a similar approach, and I agree, it is not the most flutter friendly answer.

Regarding how to read environment variables

What Flutter calls environment variables seem to be nothing more than build arguments. I would be happy to be proven wrong on this.

I don't think Dart (or Flutter) claims that String.fromEnvironment/int.fromEnvironment/etc. read "environment variables" at all.  The names are a bit misleading, but the documentation says that they read values from the "compilation configuration environment".  If you see official documentation referring to them as reading "environment variables", then you should file an issue to get that documentation adjusted.
The documentation further states:

The compilation configuration environment is not the same as the environment variables of a POSIX process. Those can be accessed on native platforms using Platform.environment from the dart:io library.

So you instead want Platform.environment, which returns a Map.  However, note that environment variables are read-only and cannot be set:

The map is unmodifiable, and its content is retrieved from the operating system on its first use.

But note that setting environment variables generally isn't very useful anyway since in most operating systems, applications typically get a copy of the environment variables inherited from the parent process, and applications can modify only their own copy.

Regarding your specific problem
(A summary of the comments to this answer.)

From what I can tell, Flutter doesn't have the ability to set true runtime environment variables.

It doesn't seem like you actually want to set environment variables within your Flutter app anyway.  You want to set environment variables in your Docker container (e.g. via command-line arguments to docker run) and then have your Flutter app read them.
But in your case, reading environment variables doesn't make sense either.  You're developing a Flutter web app, which runs in a web browser.  A script running in a client browser won't be able to read environment variables from the web server unless you do explicit work to make the server provide them.  Some ways to do that:

Use server-side scripting to embed the environment variables of interest into the served web pages/scripts.

Make your web server provide an API for clients to query the value of (specific) environment variables.

Make your Docker container generate, say, a .json file on boot that stores name-value pairs of the environment variables of interest, which your Flutter web app then could read and parse with a basic HTTP GET request.



Thanks James. To clarify, yes, I do need to set environment variables.  I need one docker image, which I will deploy to different environments, each with their own set of environment variables. I tried Platform.environment, but it doesn't seem to be supported for flutter web.  I can't find official documentation stating this, I only surmise this from my testing.

@Josh Platform.environment come from dart:io, which is implicitly available only for the Dart VM.  I don't understand what an "environment variable" would mean for Flutter web; that doesn't really make sense: a Flutter web app runs in the client browser.  If you want to read environment variables on the server, you will need to use server-side scripting.

I also don't quite understand why you need to set environment variables.  Setting environment variables usually affects only the calling process's copy of the environment and does not mutate global state.

The flutter web app will be running in a docker container. I am building a single docker image, but will need to deploy that image to different environments such as dev, stage, and prod. For example, I need the ability to pass in values when the container starts up specific to prod if I am deploying to prod. If deploying to dev, then different values for dev. I have always referred to these values as environment variables.  Does that clarify things?

The most concrete example I can give is the need for the flutter app to have configurable api endpoints. Those endpoints will be different on each environment, thus they are environment variables.  As far as I know, this is a pretty common usecase.

@Josh A Flutter web app is a web app.  It does not run in a Docker container.  It runs in a web browser.  Maybe your Docker container is serving the Flutter web app, or maybe your Flutter web app sends requests to a server process in the docker container. It makes no sense for the Flutter web app to do anything with environment variables.  Again, that is something that would be sensible for a server-side process, and a server-side process can use dart:io (if it is implemented in Dart at all).

And while you need to set environment variables, your described usage explain why you'd need Flutter to set environment variables (which is what the first sentence in your original question stated). You'd specify those environment variables to your Docker container (e.g. via command-line arguments to docker), and then a process running in that container would read those variables.

Well of course the web app is running client side. You are correct that the docker container is serving the flutter app with a web server. Regardless, I still need flutter to access values passed in when the container starts.  These would be docker run environment variables set with the -e flag.

Now if I understand you correctly, I believe you're saying I could pass in environment variables to the web server serving the flutter app, and the flutter app could read these values from the web server. That certainly sounds like an approach that would work.

Right, it's not possible for a script running in the browser to read environment variables on the server. (And that has nothing to do with Dart.) You will need to provide some mechanism to pass their values from the server to the client (e.g. via server-side scripting to inject those values directly into the served pages, via explicit requests and responses, via having your docker container generate a static .json file when started, etc.).
